# Check whether all input fields are filled out, then call function js

Tags: javascript, html, events, listener

I have a sports betting calculator, this has several input fields, as soon as all fields are filled out, the calculated table should be displayed below.

When the table is displayed, it should be possible to change the input fields; the table should then also change in real time.

HTML: `<input type="number" class ="form-control input-lg" id="quoteBack">`

JS:`document.getElementById("quoteBack").addEventListener("input", function() {});`

I am currently using the addEventListener "input" variant, this can only be used on one field.

But I want to check that all fields are filled out, then the table should appear

Comment: Add an event listener to all input fields. The event listener calls a function that check all input fields and shows the table if all input fields are filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, first of all, I think you should give the input field a unique `className`, then we just gonna check the fields that have that `className`.

For example:

```html
<input type="number" class ="form-control input-lg validated-field" id="quoteBack">
```

> I gave it a className called `validated-field`.

Then let's check those fields using JavaScript:

```js
// Get fields by className
var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("validated-field")

// Array.from will convert the HTMLCollection to Native Array.
if (Array.from(fields).length > 0) {
  // Loop
  Array.from(fields).forEach(field => {
    // Add Event for each field.
    field.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value)
      if (!e.target.value) {
        e.target.classList.add("not-valid")
      } else {
        e.target.classList.remove("not-valid")
      }
    })
  })
}
```

I just loop through the fields and add an event listener for each field.

Live Example:
https://codepen.io/nawafscript/pen/OJjEXrW